How could I get all data from dynamodb on oneshot
I have one dataframe with many columns example :
names = ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Emily', 'David']
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(1, 6), 'name': names})

df :
   id   name
0   1   John
1   2  Alice
2   3    Bob
3   4  Emily
4   5  David


In dynamodb, I saved the df with new columns, like the df below with year and month columns:
   id   name  year month
0   1   John  2024    05
1   2  Alice  2024    05
2   3    Bob  2024    05
3   4  Emily  2024    05
4   5  David  2024    05

When I have an new df, I want to check if the id exist on dynamodb or not. And I want to do that on oneshot because if I have a lot of data on the input df check one by one task time.
I want to ping dynamodb on oneshot and get if id exist or not on dynamodb. If id exist I create df_exist with all columns existing on dynamodb. if not I get in df_not_exist I id not existing on dynamodb
For example :
df :
   id   name
0   1   John
1   6  Alice
2   3    Bob
3   7  Emily
4   5  David

df_exist will be:
   id   name  year month
0   1   John  2024    05
2   3    Bob  2024    05
3   5  David  2024    05

df_not_exist will be :
   id   name
0   6  Alice
1   7  Emily

Ping to dynamodb on oneshot.
I don't want to use loop and apply. It's takes time to execute.
Thank You.
